# CMake OSX issues with Assimp

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, assimp

I am currently building a cross-platform framework and i need your help because i have troubles "deploying" the Assimp library on OSX. Let's take it from the start.

**What's the goal?**
The end user runs the CMake files , creates a project for his platform (E.g. Visual Studio Solution) runs it on his system and works on it.

**Requirements**
All the libraries used are being provided by me (e.g. sdl.lib, assimp.lib e.t.c) and CMake uses them to link against the executable.
One of the libraries used is the assimp library. So in Windows and Linux i normally provide them with the assimp.lib and dll files and the .a and .so files and it works fine.

**What's the problem then?**
So the problem is that with OSX i cannot do the same.
I have built assimp on my macbook with CMake and it has created the following files ->
libassimpd.3.1.1.dylib , libassimpd.3.dylib, libassimpd.dylib .
Which is fine and works on my computer . But the problem is when i try to "ship" those files on another computer . The user as normally would do creates the XCode.project with CMake opens the .proj file and builds successfully the target. When it runs it though he gets a runtime error which has a path from my computer (where assimp was built from source)
**/Users/.../assimp3.1.1-build -> Reference to libassimp.3.dylib Image not Found**.
I don't know why this happens .

Has anyone else faced this ? Solved it somehow? 
I don't want the user to be building Assimp on his computer before using the framework because the enduser is supposed to be a novice in computer graphics and we already involved the use of CMake , we don't want to make it any more complicated .

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I've only managed to get this to work by building assimp as a static library.